# Search more columns - Python , Outlook

Tags: python, loops, search, outlook

the code below does a search on name only. However I would like to do a search on e-email using more columns option. Is there any way to do it ?

[image]

```
import win32com.client

search_string = 'doe@doe.com'

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
gal = outlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = gal.AddressEntries
ae = entries[search_string]
email_address = None

if 'EX' == ae.Type:
    eu = ae.GetExchangeUser()
    email_address = eu.PrimarySmtpAddress

if 'SMTP' == ae.Type:
    email_address = ae.Address

print('Email address: ', email_address)
```

Comment: So what does the UI have to do with yoru code? What is it exactly that you are trying to do and can't?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I've edited my post so now it's much clearer to understand. Basically what I wanna do is make a search on more columns because the code above does a search on names only and I'm getting wrong result.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to search on?

Comment: Hi,
I'm trying to search on e-mail

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching, you can let Outlook find the match - call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`.

Comment: I am using this method to check the user exist in the organization or not.
Problem - I got very few matches. So i checked manually and found match. Does the Global Address List being used in Python Library - win32com is Offline Dump or does it check on request?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - do you mean you want to find multiple matches? Or that there is a single match, but CreateRecipient cannot be resolve a given name at all?